# Describe equivelence classes

Tags: abstract-algebra

The problem is

> Let S be the set of integer and let R be the set of pairs $(a,b)$ such that $a+b$ is even. Describe the equivalence classes.

My solution was $a + b = k$ for some even integer $k.$ Therefore, $a = k - b$ for some even integer $k.$

$[a] = \{k - b \mid k \in \mathbb Z\}$.

Also, $b = k - a$ for some even integer $k.$

$[b] = \{k - a \mid k \in \mathbb Z\}$.

I don't know whether or not my solution is correct. I personally think my solution is missing something but don't know what to add. Please help me with this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Hint: there are only two equivalence classes here...

Comment: ajotatxe yes I mean ∈. Thank you for pointing it out. DonAntonio So I have to have more than two classes?

Comment: To correct what you've written, $[a]=\{k-b~|~k\in 2\Bbb Z\}$.  Notice the difference between the sets $\Bbb Z = \{\dots,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,\dots\}$ and $2\Bbb Z=\{\dots,-4,-2,0,2,4,\dots\}$.  If you want to talk about even integers, you mean to use the second of these sets not the first.  That being said, writing the equivalence class in this way does not actually help all that much.  Remember your definition of equivalence class: $[a]=\{b~:~(a,b)\in \mathcal{R}\}$, that is to say in this case $[a]=\{k-a~:~k\in2\Bbb Z\}$, which can be simplified further using the other hints you've been given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Let S be the set of integers and let R be the set of pairs $(a,b)$ such that $a+b$ is even. Describe the equivalence classes."

$(1)$  All elements in $\{\ldots, - 4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6, \ldots\}$ (i.e., all even integers) are in one equivalence class, because when we pick any two even integers, their sum is even.

All elements in $\{\ldots, -3, -1, 1, 3, 5, \ldots\}$ (i.e., all odd integers) are in another equivalence class, because when we pick any two odd integers, their sum is even.

The two equivalence classes partition the set of integers, $\mathbb Z$.

---

To be more precise, we'll show that all even numbers are related to one another, and all odd numbers are related to one another, and that no even/odd pair is related to one another, under the given equivalence relation:

Let's take $a$ to be any ***even*** integer.  So $a = 2k$ for some integer $k$.  When we add any other even integer to $a$, say we add $x = 2m$, then we get $a + x = (2k + 2m) = 2(k+m)$ which is again even.  So adding two even integers results in an even integer.

Let's take $b$ to be any ***odd*** integer.  So $b = 2k+1$ for some integer $k$.  Suppose we add another odd integer to $b$, say $y = 2n+ 1$.  When we add $b + y = 2k+1 + 2n + 1 = 2 k + 2n +2 = 2(k+n+1)$, and hence the sum of any two odd integers is always even.

To show the two equivalence classes are disjoint, let us take any even integer $c = 2p$ and any odd integer $d = 2q+1$ where p and q are integers, and add them: $c + d = 2p + (2q + 1) = 2(p+q) +1$, which is odd, and so it is never the case that an even integer c added to an odd  integer d, is in the relation.  Hence  the set of all even integers, and the set of all odd integers, comprise the two equivalence classes, and their union is $\mathbb Z$, itself.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

The sum of two odd numbers is even. The sum of two even numbers is even. The sum of an odd number and an even number is odd.

Comment: Should I have two cases: odd cases and even cases? Such as [odd] = {sum of odd integer} and [even] = {sum of even integer}

Comment: @vnsoshi "{sum of odd integer}" sounds awkward and does not sound like you yet understood the hint or the problem.  Consider what the equivalence class of $[1]$ is.  The equivalence class of $[1]$ is the set of all integers who when added to $1$ is even.  $1+1$ is even, so $1$ is an element of $[1]$.  Also $3+1$ is even, so $3$ is in $[1]$.  $2+1$ is not even so $2$ is not included.  Continuing in this fashion, you can build a list of elements that are versus aren't in $[1]$ and should spot a pattern.  Then notice how $[1]$ compares to $[3]$ and $[5]$ and so on...